# What does “term” mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The word "term" has a lot of meanings. What does it  mean in the following context?

> The term complication is a nod to high-end watchmaking and refers to a function a watch performs beyond telling the hour and minute.

Comment: It refers to the word "complication", identifying it as the word being discussed/defined.

Comment: I would expect it to be written as "the term *complication*" or similar (setting off the actual term via formatting) in order to make it clear what term is being referred to.

Comment: Indeed, that's the proper way to write a sentence like that. But not everyone knows all the formal rules of writing, and this omission is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its most popular sense:

> A word or phrase used to describe a thing or to express a concept,
>   especially in a particular kind of language or branch of study,

Your sentence is describing what the word **complication** means in the given context.

There's no such thing as [term complication](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=term%20complication), in case that was causing the confusion for you